# Flutter Firebase web integration

Tags: flutter, firebase

Hello I am getting flutter firebase web error.

I initialized web properly but I am getting this error when I try to use firebase Firestore functions.

I have no idea about this error ....

Is there anyone who has this error before ?

Thangs for reading.

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: firebase.firestore() takes either no argument or a Firebase App instance.
(app/invalid-app-argument).
    at Object.e [as firestore] (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js:1:19409)
    at Object.getFirestoreInstance
    (http://localhost:5000/packages/cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/utils/utils.dart.lib.js:1226:79)
    at get [_delegate] (http://localhost:5000/packages/cloud_firestore_web/src/write_batch_web.dart.lib.js:778:59)
    at cloud_firestore_web.FirebaseFirestoreWeb.new.doc
    (http://localhost:5000/packages/cloud_firestore_web/src/write_batch_web.dart.lib.js:811:76)
    at cloud_firestore.FirebaseFirestore.__.doc
    (http://localhost:5000/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart.lib.js:1456:84)
    at database_service.DataBaseServcie.new.read
    (http://localhost:5000/packages/root/img_files/img_slider.dart.lib.js:5997:65)
    at read.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at database_service.DataBaseServcie.new.read
    (http://localhost:5000/packages/root/img_files/img_slider.dart.lib.js:5992:20)
    at http://localhost:5000/packages/timetowork/screen/posting/posting_main_screen.dart.lib.js:15869:44
    at [_handleTap] (http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/material/icon_button.dart.lib.js:42254:31)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.invokeCallback
    (http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart.lib.js:198:18)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handleTapUp
    (http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.lib.js:411:42)
    at [_checkUp] (http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.lib.js:217:12)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handlePrimaryPointer
    (http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.lib.js:166:23)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handleEvent
    (http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart.lib.js:444:16)
    at [_dispatch] (http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart.lib.js:86:9)
    at http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart.lib.js:112:26
    at LinkedMap.new.forEach (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:27745:11)
    at [_dispatchEventToRoutes]
    (http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart.lib.js:110:29)
    at pointer_router.PointerRouter.new.route
    (http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart.lib.js:105:37)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handleEvent
    (http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:367:26)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.dispatchEvent
    (http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:355:24)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.dispatchEvent
    (http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:5440:13)
    at [_handlePointerEventImmediately]
    (http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:331:14)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handlePointerEvent
    (http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:305:43)
    at [_flushPointerEventQueue] (http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:295:14)
    at [_handlePointerDataPacket] (http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:286:54)
    at Object.invoke1 (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:191747:7)
    at _engine.EnginePlatformDispatcher.__.invokeOnPointerDataPacket (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:171943:15)
    at [_onPointerData] (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:172879:49)
    at http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:173317:28
    at http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:173273:16
    at loggedHandler (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:172978:11)
```

Comment: Care to share the code that is generating the error?

Comment: @tomerpacific I think there is no error in codes, cause it's working well in mobile app.

Comment: @DaegilPyo I am facing this now, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

1. run `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`
2. run `dart fix --apply`

Comment: Worked for me, thank you, without your answer, I would lost more hours

Comment: No problem, enjoy coding ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading your packages at:

firebase_core: ^1.20.0

cloud_firestore: ^3.4.2

then flutter clean / flutter pub get